# Ejecutar sql de acuerdo a user logueado

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Necesito traer el usuario logueado para poder ejecutar la siguiente procedure. Mi controlador es el siguiente:

```
class CtacteController < ApplicationController

def show
@ctacte = FirebirdDBModel.connection.execute("SELECT * from 
ctacte_resumen(current_user,2019,12,2019,12,0,1) ")
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes interpolar el valor (utilizando `#{}`) de `current_user`, de lo contrario estás pasando como tal el valor `"current_user"` y no su contenido:

```
FirebirdDBModel.connection.execute("SELECT * from ctacte_resumen(#{current_user},2019,12,2019,12,0,1)")
```

Si `current_user` es un objeto del modelo de usuario (e.g. `User`) debes entonces obtener el `id`; por ejemplo (asumiendo que existe la columna `id`):

```
FirebirdDBModel.connection.execute("SELECT * from ctacte_resumen(#{current_user.id},2019,12,2019,12,0,1)")
```